# Can't install react libraries on linux using yarn: error: 00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm installing the library:  [react-jsonschema-form](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This are the instructions I'm following:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
npm install @rjsf/core --save
npm install --save bootstrap
npm init react-app formapp
yarn add react-jsonschema-form
```

But when I try to start the App I get the following error:

```
Module not found: 'react-jsonschema-form'
```

I think this is because this line is failling:

```
yarn add react-jsonschema-form
```

I gives the following error:

```
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'
```

Comment: I don't think it is related to react or js but rather to a broken `yarn` installation. Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3708). Let me know if it was of any help.

Comment: @subashMahapatra Yep, it was that